# How to use JS/Jquery-Functions within DataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Im using datatables with serverside processing. No problems so far.

Now i have added a link to a col:

```
<a href="#" class="clickme" id="1">test</a>
```

Following js:

```
$(".clickme").click(function(){
  alert("test");
});
```

Thats the table code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#table').DataTable( {
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "destroy": true,
                    "ajax": "url/to/test.php",
                    "language": {
                        "url": "/../includes/DataTables/german.json"
                    }
                } );
            } );
```

Actually the alert window should open when clicking a link. But nothing happens. No warnings in console etc...

Could you help me finding the problem? I think the reason is that datables needs its own initialization of jquery library - but how to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: is the *"click me"* code inside `$(document).ready..`? The idea of different jQuery library initialization is incorrect but the elements need to exist when you run that code

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the click-me code was in $(document).ready-block... The code posted by Tobias Teichner worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to bind the click listener on the table itself instead of the cells, as they are not present from the beginning.

Place the following code block inside of your $(document).ready block.

```html
$("#table").on('click', '.clickme', function(){
  alert("test");
});
```

Comment: That's it! I have already tried to insert my above code in $(document).ready but that did not work. Your code works! Thank you!